# A union of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'd really like some help with the next question:
We're given a series of sets $B_i$ ($i\in\mathbb N$) such that each set's cardinality is $c$. I'm asked to prove that the the cardinality of $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N}B_i$ also equals to c. Any clues or hints will be very helpful!
Thank you!

**Sadly I cannot use any cardinality arithmetic**

$c=\aleph$

Comment: @Masacroso Isn't, technically, $\mathfrak c=2^{\aleph_0}=\beth_1$ ?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli yes this is the definition we were given.

Comment: Well, I assumed the continuum hypothesis, but your expression is more formal @G.Sassatelli

Answer (score 0):

As given in in the comments above I assume that $c$ is defined as the cardinality of the power set $\mathcal{P}$ of a countable, non-finite set e.g. of $\Bbb N$

w.l.o.g let the $B_i$ be disjoint and assume $c = |B_i| = |\mathcal{P}(N_i)|$ for some countable $N_i$, so there exists a bijection $f_i: B_i \to \mathcal{P}(N_i)$. Again w.l.o.g take the $N_i$ to be disjoint.

Then there exists also a bijection $$f:\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N} B_i \to \bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N} \mathcal{P}(N_i)$$ by $f|_{B_i} = f_i$

and so:

$$\begin{align*}c &= |B_i| &&\le \left|\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N} B_i\right| \\&= \left|\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N} \mathcal{P}(N_i)\right| &&\le \left|\mathcal{P}\left(\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N} N_i\right)\right| \\ &= c\end{align*}$$

due to the fact that $\bigcup\limits_{i\in\Bbb N} N_i$ is countable as a countable union of countable sets.

Comment: Thank you so much Gono! But what should I do if the sets aren't disjoint?

Comment: Hey..sorry for bothering but what shall I do when the case I stated above occurs?

Comment: If the $B_i$ are not disjoint consider $$\tilde{B_i} = B_i \setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} B_j$$, then the $\tilde{B_i}$ are disjoint by construction and $$\bigcup_{i \in \Bbb N} B_i = \bigcup_{i\in \Bbb N} \tilde{B_i}$$ so you get the same set and hence the same cardinality…